# How to get scrollTop property while user is still scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a website that uses AJAX to refresh a chat section in realtime. I am working on making the chat scroll to the bottom when the user sends a message but stay scrollable if messages from other people are loading. This all works, by the way. Anyways, whenever the new data from the AJAX request replaces the current data, it scrolls to the top of the div. I got around this by getting the div's scrollTop property whenever the user scrolls and setting the div's scrollTop to the previous scrollTop that I saved whenever the AJAX data comes in. When I do this, the jquery event only executes and gets the scrollTop after I've stopped scrolling, which causes a jump in the scroll location if I'm still scrolling when the data refreshes. Does anyone know how I can get the scrollTop value even if the user is still in the process of scrolling?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Is it possible for you not to replace the complete contents of your div, but instead only adding the new messages? That way, scrolling should be transparently handled by the browser.

Comment: even better.. use virtual-repeat.

Comment: @Pharaoh I am going to work on that later, but for now I want a quick solution so I can stop worrying about the chat for a bit and get to more important parts of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the scroll top position inside:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    })
```

Everytime, you move scroll bar this function is executed, if its is default window (otherwise use respective element).